# I want to view google page sponsored ads (next to search result section) from another country. I am from india

Tags: google-ads

I want to view google page sponsored ads (next to search result section) from another country. I am from india.

I am currently getting ads related to my geograhical region thats India.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using the "Ad Preview and Diagnosis" tool available in the "Tools and Analysis" tab of your AdWords account. This will allow you to select a location and enter a keyword to see how it looks on a sample search results page.